# How to use a while loop to count the number of times a specific number appears in a list?

Tags: python

I have a question from an assignment:

> Write a program that takes a series of numbers (ending in 0) and
>   counts the number of times that the number 100 appears in the list.
>   For example, for the series 2, 6, 100, 50, 101, 100, 88, 0, it would
>   output 2.

I have been successfully able to do this using a for loop, but I am supposed to execute it with a while loop.

My for loop is:

```
list = [2, 6, 100, 50, 101, 100, 88, 0]
n=list[0]
total=0
if n !=0:
  for n in list:
    if n == 100:
      total +=1
print (total)
```

However I can't seem to get the output of 2 with a while loop. I've tried a few variations and the output is 0, one of which is :

```
list = [2, 6, 100, 50, 101, 100, 88, 0]
n=list[0]
total=0
if n !=0:
    while n in list == 100:
      total +=1
print (total)
```

Can someone advise the easiest way to achieve the same output using a while loop? Thanks!

Comment: You could use a counter variable that you'll increment every loop and limit the while as `while i < len(list)` but it's dumb because it's a for loop...

Comment: tha's a homework

Comment: The output of the first code is `2`. Why is there a second code? What is `n=list[0]` supposed to be doing? Why `if n !=0:`? Don't call your variable `list`, that's bad for your health.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set an index as 0 and use while loop to keep looking until index is the same as the length of the list. in each iteration check if the value of that index of the list equals 100 and if it does increase total by 1

```py
nums = [2, 6, 100, 50, 101, 100, 88, 0]
index = 0
total = 0
while index < len(nums):
    if nums[index] == 100:
        total += 1
    index +=1
print(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to take care of this would be to keep an iteration/index value and increment in the while loop. You appear to be thinking of

for item in list syntax.

try this.

```
list = [2, 6, 100, 50, 101, 100, 88, 0]
iter = 0
n=list[iter]
total=0
while n != 0:
    if(n == 100):
        total += 1
    iter += 1
    n = list[iter]

print (total)
```

This assumes you will always have a 0 ending the list.

Comment: does it still give 2 for this list `list = [2, 0, 100, 50, 101, 100, 88, 0]`?

Comment: Since the original question said that it assumes ending with 0 it ends at after two iterations and doesn't count anything after [2, 0,.......]

Answer (score 0):

Although this could be made easier by replacing the while loop but I assumed its your requirement:

```
list = eval(input('Enter List: '))
n, total, a = True, 0, 0
length = len(list)
while n is True:
    if a == length:
        n = False
    elif list[a] == 100:
        total += 1
    a += 1
print(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can stick with while True and use the **enumerate** method in order to loop both through the index of the list and the elements of the list, like this:

```py
your_list = [2, 6, 100, 50, 101, 100, 88, 0]

counter = 0
index = 0
while True:
    for index,element in enumerate(your_list):
        if 100 == element:
            counter += 1

    #break while:
    if index == len(your_list) - 1:
        print(counter)
        break
```